# Ubuntu Hyper-V doesn't allocate dynamic memory

Tags: virtualization, ram, hyper-v

Month ago, I've updated some Linux core packages. Then, dynamic memory allocation stopped working - Hyper-V shows that more memory has been allocated but when I `cat /proc/meminfo` it shows the starting amount and swap is heavily utilized (I'm using some heavy-memory app).

Is it necessary to update configuration somehow?

Answer (score 1):

I've been having the same problem. It still isn't fixed, but the virtual servers run much better with a static allocation of RAM.

Comment: You need to provide better answer with evidence.